# Iterating Over CSV Deleting Analyzed Data

Tags: python, list, csv, append

Hello I am trying to take a CSV file and iterate over each customers data. To explain, each customer has data for 12 months. I want to analyze their yearly data, save the correlations of this data to a new list and loop this until all customers have been analyzed.

For instance here is what a customers data might look like (simplified case):
[image]

I have been able to get this to work to generate correlations in a CSV of one customers data. However, there are thousands of customers in my datasheet. I want to use a nested for loop to get all of the correlation values for each customer into a list/array. The list would have a row of a specific customer's correlations then the next row would be the next customer.

Here is my current code:

```
import numpy
from numpy import genfromtxt
overalldata = genfromtxt('C:\Users\User V\Desktop\CUSTDATA.csv', delimiter=',')
emptylist = []
overalldatasubtract = overalldata[13::]
#This is where I try to use the four loop to go through all the customers. I     don't know if len will give me all the rows or the number of columns.
for x in range(0,len(overalldata),11):
    for x in range(0,13,1):
            cust_months = overalldata[0:x,1]
            cust_balancenormal = overalldata[0:x,16]
            cust_demo_one = overalldata[0:x,2]
            cust_demo_two = overalldata[0:x,3]
            num_acct_A = overalldata[0:x,4]
            num_acct_B = overalldata[0:x,5]
    #Correlation Calculations
            demo_one_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
            demo_two_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, cust_demo_two)[1,0]
            demo_one_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
            demo_one_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
            demo_two_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, cust_demo_two)[1,0]
            demo_two_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, cust_demo_two)[1,0]

            result_correlation = [demo_one_corr_balance, demo_two_corr_balance, demo_one_corr_acct_a, demo_one_corr_acct_b, demo_two_corr_acct_a, demo_two_corr_acct_b]

result_correlation_combined = emptylist.append(result_correlation)
#This is where I try to delete the rows I have already analyzed.
overalldata = overalldata[11**x::]

print result_correlation_combined
print overalldatasubtract
```

It seemed that my subtraction method was working, but when I tried it with my larger data set, I realized my method is totally wrong.

Would you do this a different way? I think that it can work, but I cannot find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same variable `x` for both loops. In the second loop `x` goes from 0 to 12 whatever the customer, and since you set the line number only with `x` you're stuck on the first customer.

Your double loop should rather look like this :

```
# loop over the customers
for x_customer in range(0,len(overalldata),12):
    # loop over the months
    for x_month in range(0,12,1):
        # line number: x
        x = x_customer*12 + x_month
        ...
```

I changed the bounds and steps of the loops because :

- **loop 1:** there are 12 months so 12 lines per customer -> step = 12
- **loop 2:** there are 12 months, so month number ranges from 0 to 11 -> `range(0,12,1)`

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be what I was trying to do, however I am still not getting any output.

I want to save those resulting correlations to the:
result_correlation_combined = emptylist.append(result_correlation)

However, this does not appear to be saving anything, as I keep getting an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved the problem: It was a problem with the placement of my for loops. A simple indentation problem. Thank you for the help to above poster.

for x_customer in range(0,len(overalldata),12):

```
    for x in range(0,13,1):
            cust_months = overalldata[0:x,1]
            cust_balancenormal = overalldata[0:x,16]
            cust_demo_one = overalldata[0:x,2]
            cust_demo_two = overalldata[0:x,3]
            num_acct_A = overalldata[0:x,4]
            num_acct_B = overalldata[0:x,5]
#Correlation Calculations
            demo_one_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
            demo_two_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, cust_demo_two)[1,0]
            demo_one_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
            demo_one_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
            demo_two_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, cust_demo_two)[1,0]
            demo_two_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, cust_demo_two)[1,0]

            result_correlation = [(demo_one_corr_balance),(demo_two_corr_balance),(demo_one_corr_acct_a),(demo_one_corr_acct_b),(demo_two_corr_acct_a),(demo_two_corr_acct_b)]
            numpy.savetxt('correlationoutput.csv', (result_correlation))
    result_correlation_combined = emptylist.append([result_correlation])
    cust_delete_list = [0,(x_customer),1]
    overalldata = numpy.delete(overalldata, (cust_delete_list), axis=0)
```